# Bind two properties to one textbox text

Tags: winforms, data-binding, textbox

suppose I have one class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    ... (some more properties here)

    public int Min {get;set;}
    public int Max {get;set;}

    ... (some more properties here)
}
```

Now I place a textbox in the designer and I want it to display Min and Max as text seperated with a dash.
For example if Min=3 and Max=10 then the textbox should display "3-10".
When the text is changed / the binding is updated it should parse the string "3-10" like this:

Split the string by '-' and parse the two strings with int.Parse(...)
If that doesn't work (an exception happens) I'd like to react on that somehow. For example displaying an error message would work.

How do I do this?
The VisualStudio designer only allows me to bind the Text to one property of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying 3-10, you can write

```
TextBoxName.Text=Min + "-" + Max;
```

and, You may raise an exception and show the MessageBox as:

```
try{
    int.Parse(Min);
    int.Parse(Max);
}
catch(Exception ae){
    MessageBox.Show("Some error message");
}
```

**EDIT:**
For Binding,

```
textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text",this,"StringVariable");
                    //Text property,this form, name of the variable.
```

where StringVariable is some property returning Min + "-" + Max;

Comment: Yes but I don't want to assign the value directly to the Text property. I need to solve it with databinding.